# Reading and Writing in Python Specific Issue

Tags: python, file-io

Something is wrong with my code but I'm not sure why it's wrong!

```
import os

os.system('cp $HOME/Documents/MATLAB/processFates.m $HOME/Documents/Outputs/test2')

write = open('matlabEx.submit','w+')

write.write("""
#$ -N matlab_example
#$ -o job.out
#$ -e job.error
#$ -cwd
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -pe orte 2
#$ -V

matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r \"fwhm = processFates('FWHM',200)\"
"""

write.close()

os.system('qsub matlabEx.submit')
```

It's not writing the file. What is wrong?

Comment: What actually happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot a closing parenthesis on the `write.write` call.

Comment: @alvarezcl: In the future, if Python gives you a `SyntaxError`, do a quick check for mistakes like that. It's usually something simple.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to set the python environment:

**#!/usr/bin/env python**